# Is there a way to Limit to 100 users when I get users form github users?

Tags: android, github, retrofit

I am retrofit :

https://api.github.com/users

I want to know how can I limit 100 users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `per_page` parameter:

https://api.github.com/users?per_page=100

And then check the `Link` headers response and check the `rel="next"` link, it should contain the `since` parameter in which you set the last id you got in that previous call:

https://api.github.com/users?per_page=100&since=135

Even though 100 seems to be the default value as it says:

> You can specify how many items to receive (up to a maximum of 100);

Check its docs: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/#changing-the-number-of-items-received

Comment: Thanks . May I ask one more , String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/" the @GET("users") , if I @GET("users?per_page=100) , that mean if I want to see 101 user , what to do ?

Comment: If you ask for the page and then check the headers, you'll see the `Link: <https://api.github.com/users?per_page=100&since=135>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/users{?since}>; rel="first"` so the next page is https://api.github.com/users?per_page=100&since=135 and you have to send the `?per_page=100&since={since}"` each time with the last returned id

Comment: I've seen in this api call some calls are paginated with the `page` parameter and others like that of the users with `since` so the only way of knowing for sure which one is used is by checking the headers when you get a 200 response. You can use the network tab in web inspector in a web browser to check which one needs a specific call and if you get a `304 (Not modified)` response use `CTRL + F5` to force refresh and not to use the cache.